# UNRESOLVED dependency for grails1.3.7

Tags: grails, rabbitmq

I am using `grails 1.3.7` And I'm trying to add `rabbitMq` dependency in build.config file.But I am not getting this dependency resolved.Which version of `RabbitMQ` should I use for `grails 1.3.7`.I have used `compile "org.grails.plugins:rabbitmq:2.0.0"` and `compile "org.grails.plugins:rabbitmq:1.0.0"`.
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

In 1.3.7, the BuildConfig dependencies were generally just used for plain JAR files. Grails plugins are installed with "install-plugin". See the user guide for 1.3.7:
http://docs.grails.org/1.3.7/

in particular, the "[list-plugins](http://docs.grails.org/1.3.7/ref/Command%20Line/list-plugins.html)" and "[install-plugin](http://docs.grails.org/1.3.7/ref/Command%20Line/install-plugin.html)" commands.

Version 1.0.0 and a few earlier versions should be available to you at the plugins repo: http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/rabbitmq/